# How to get the returned value from a find() in mongoDb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, authentication, passport.js

I am using **mongoDb** to create a login page (That's not  a official login)

For the login system I am using, **express**, **session-express** and **passport**.

There is a file for **passport-config** to get the information sent by the login form and after comapre the info with the daabase.

file: **'passport-config.js**'

```js
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local'
LocalStrategy.Strategy
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt' // to encrypt the password

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByEmail(email) // calls the 'getUserByEmail()' and it uses the email taken by the login form


                // the rest of the code...
    }
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser)) // calls authenticateUser sending the info from the form
}

export default initialize
```

The file **'passport-config.js'** exports the function, then I import it in **server.js**. As parameters I use (passport, **function to find the user by email, function to find the user by id**)

the **server.js**

```js
import initializePassaport from '../passport-config.js' // import the function from passport-config.js

import passport from 'passport'

import users from "../models/User.js"; // get the model Schema from the users database

initializePassaport(
    passport,
    email =>  users.findOne({"email": email}, {}, (err, user) => user) // get the email that was sent as a parameter of the getUserByEmail function inside the passport-config.js file
        id =>  users.findById(id, (err, user) => {email = user} => user) // same thing, but with id
)


//more code...
```

My problem is when I send the parameters in '**server.js**', the expected value was to find the user by emai. But instead, it sends a others values. The problem is that Apparently the value sent by the find() in mongoDb can't be outside the function.

I put a console . log:  **"email =>  users.findOne({"email": email}, {}, (err, user) => {console.log(user})"**
and it return the right value in the console. But it doesn't send the right value to the funciton

I've already tried to put a **return**. But It also doesn't work.

And I tried to research how to get this value, but I didn't find anything for this problem

This code has worked before using just a common array without a real database. Like:

```js
const users = [ // this is an exmaple
    {
    "id": '167252944716', 
    "username": 'adm',
    "email": 'adm@adm', 
    "password": '$2b$12$G/EwhnXj5P/y1NGTb5Sq4.OTY5m.BMferVHVJ27AtZGn8vt6qDsvi' //encrypted
    }
]


initializePassaport(
    passport,
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)
```

I don't Know what I can I do to send this info to the **passport-config.js**, is there a way to fix it? if it's not clear please let me know to improve it, thank you!

Comment: Can you post the `getUserByEmail` code?

Comment: the `getUserByEmail` is in the second file (server.js). It uses `findOne()`to find the user in the database. `email =>  users.findOne({"email": email}, {}, (err, user) => user)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findOne and findById are async functions so it would return a promise, you need to resolve it by using await keyword or .then() method try using something like this:

```
const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
    }
};
```